# How to Recalculate / Refresh the specific cells in Excel interop?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Lets say I have a marker, "#Refresh#", on some cells, which indicate that these cells need to be recalculated at later stage.

So my question is:

**What should I do to recalculate only these specific cells that are marked as "#Refresh#"**?

I notice that if I do

`Excel.Range range = Worksheet.UsedRange`

it will return all the range objects, including those without "#Refresh#" markers. Is there any way I can get the marked range objects only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I think I found quite a useful example on MSDN that was about searching for text in worksheet range. It'd be very helpful, I suppose. So I've shared the link below in case someone is looking for that as well.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a(v=VS.100).aspx[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)